# "Unrecognized configuration parameter: qreplace_function" trying to backup a database

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

I am new to PostgreSQL and I am trying to backup a database with the *pg_dump* utility.

I am using this command:

```
/opt/PostgresPlus/9.4AS/bin/pg_dump -U (username) -f /opt/PostgresPlus/9.4AS//pgbackup/db_name.sql dbname -p 5432
```

and I am encountering this error:

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: 
>   ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "qreplace_function"

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have not used  PostgreSQL. You are using  PostgresPlus created by EnterpriseDB.

The parameter `qreplace_funtion` is mentioned in EnterpriseDB's [document](http://www.enterprisedb.com/rn-pgplus-as84-sp2-release-notes) (page 21). I guess this is a typical privilege problem.

OR, if you use PostgreSQL but run PostgrePlus's pg_dump, try original PostgreSQL's pg_dump.